# visual studio 2012 most recent projects missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Windows taskbar and start menu the list of recently opened projects/solutions is blank. However, in VS the general options are marked to display 10 items. The list used to display, but recently I noticed that it disappeared. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, but I had the sense that other menu items were missing as well.

What I did was go into Tools => Import & Export Settings, choose Reset all settings, and then select the same profile as when I installed Visual Studio. (General Development Settings.) That fixed the issue.