# Visual Studio 2012 not showing recent projects which I have worked on

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

This is a trivial question regarding Visual Studio 2012. I have looked on the web and specifically on Stackoverflow but have not found what I need.

When I open solutions in VS2012 they do not appear on the Start Page under the Recent Projects section of the Start Page. Also they do not appear under the File->Recent Projects List menu option.

I know it's no biggie but it would save me time instead of having to browse to the solution file each time I open a project/solution.

I have attached a screenshot to show what I mean.
[image: Boxed in Red where the recent projects would normally appear]

Thanks for any reply. :)

UPDATE

I tried reseting the Tools-> Import And Export settings.
It says the settings were saved but with errors. Specifically the error message being:

```
Your settings were reset, but there were some errors.
```

Error 1:  Projects and Solutions: Unable to import property 'ProjectItemTemplatesLocation' because it contains invalid data '%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Templates\ItemTemplates'.
Error 2:  Projects and Solutions: Unable to import property 'ProjectTemplatesLocation' because it contains invalid data '%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Templates\ProjectTemplates'.
Error 3:  Projects and Solutions: Unable to import property 'ProjectsLocation' because it contains invalid data '%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Projects'.

The current settings that I have for the Projects and Solutions options are as shown in the image attached below. I am certain this can't be right but I am not sure what it is that I have to be pointing to:
[image: Tools->Options->Project and Solutions-.General]

One think of is the

Comment: this might solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402767/visual-studio-2012-most-recent-projects-missing

Comment: @Sentinel Hi Sentinel, I think you are deffinitely on the right track. When I tried this I recieved an error message. I have added the error message to the question under "Update" I am not sure what the correct paths should be for the Projects And Solutions from the Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General. I do think it is something to do with this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be my wrong interpretation but the error refers to `%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Templates\ItemTemplates` 
,in your settings (screenshot) there's no `Templates` parent folder for `ItemTemplates`. However I cannot check if this is a wrong location since I'm currently working on a device which only has vs2010, but just for reference these are my (default) settings

[image: vs2010 project settings]

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sentinel, Yes I agree. I have Visual Studio 2010 installed and it has the same settings as you have shown. The thing is Visual Studio 2012 does not have these folders in the Documents folder. I  think I may need to get it reinstalled. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the values in Tools->Options->Enviroment->General

[image]